# "warning: unable to unlink" when dealing with git submodules

Tags: git

I installed a submodule on branch `try-submodules` when trying to checkout the master branch (which had no submodules), I get the following warning:

warning: unable to unlink public/docs/blueprint: Operation not permitted
   Switched to branch 'master'

Browsing the file directory, I can see that everything checked out just fine EXCEPT my `blueprint` subdirectory still exists, even though it is not present in the `master` branch.

I've found a few discussions of this problem: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-11/msg00756.html, but no solutions.

Any ideas?

Comment: If this is Windows, I can comment that sometimes Windows randomly prevents me from deleting empty directories until the next system reboot. These problems don't have anything to do with git, though I haven't actually bothered looking into where they come from.

Perhaps you could get yourself a copy of Process Explorer and see if there are any open file handles on the directory... and which process owns them.

Comment: Do you have permission to delete `public/docs/blueprint`?  Is this checkout perhaps being used as an active web directory?  Is `blueprint` or something in it owned by the web server and not you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same problem, as a workaround you can remove the submodule dir with 'rm -rf' (force is important here) and checkout the branch again

Comment: Thanks. It's annoying that I've got to use a workaround, but did work just fine.